# How to add a material to a single face?

Tags: materials

Whenever I assign a material to the selected faces of a cube, it paints the entire cube. I've seen questions like this, and I've done everything they say to do in the comments, yet nothing seems to work.

[image: Cube]

Comment: You only have one material for your object, therefore the whole object gets the material.  Add at least one more material.

Comment: Add two materials, then assign _both_ materials to different parts of the mesh.

Answer (score 2):

First Enter editmode then choose the face you want ,and in the material 
section press plus and under it press assign and the new material will be the applied only in the face selected.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but that's what iv'e been doing. Any other ideas, possibly?

Comment: what i can see in your image that when you press assign you assign your face to the red color

Comment: be sure that you have two materials not just one

Comment: Well, did you assign the other faces to a different material?

Comment: No,when making material for first time blender apply it to the whole mesh so it doesn't need to apply other faces to the other material, but you can make it it isn't wrong

Comment: you must select the other faces and the other material and then assign them .